# How to correctly use bind for addEventListener JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am creating events for a bunch of different buttons using a for loop. I want to pass the value of the button pressed onto another method when it is clicked:

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='button']");

for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener("click", displayOutput.bind(this, button[i].value))
}

function displayOutput(buttonValue) {

    var value = buttonValue;
}
```

This code works, but I just need clarification on what is going on here. Most of the resources I have seen for bind, do not include using "this" in the parameters.

Why is it needed here? For example, when removed the code does not work. Does it have something to do with the fact I am trying to pass a variable to the function rather than binding an object to it?:

```
//"this" removed from displayOutput.bind function parameters

for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener("click", displayOutput.bind(button[i].value)) 
}
```

Comment: may have to do with the value of `i` at the END of the loop

Comment: @Bravo - Not in this case, since it's only used during the loop (not after).

Comment: The first argument of `Function#bind` is the `this` value to be used inside the function. Which is not the `this` button you would normally expect... But anyway that doesn't matter. What matters is that `button[i].value` is the second argument to `bind`, which makes it the first argument of the bound function.

Comment: The first argument for bind is the `thisArg`, it isnt optional (ie something has to be passed for it). If your function isnt using the `this` keyword inside it then it isnt needed, in those cases just pass `null`

Comment: Why `.bind()` at all? Instead of the loop use the `.forEach()` method: `button.forEach(function(btn) { btn.addEventListener("click", () => displayOutput(btn.value)) })` or `for (let i = ...; ...; ... ) { button[i].addEventListener("click", () => displayOutput(button[i].value)) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), the **first** argument you give defines what `this` to call the function with. The rest of the `bind` arguments tell it what arguments to call the function with.

> For example, when removed the code does not work.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
>     button[i].addEventListener("click", displayOutput.bind(button[i].value)) 
> }
> ```

By removing the initial `this`, you're creating a function that will call call `displayOutput` with `this` set to `button[i].value` (rather that `button[i].value` being the first argument). If your `displayOutput` function is in strict mode (`"use strict";` or a module or a `class`, etc.), you *could* use `this` instead of `buttonValue` within `displayOutput`:

```
// Possible in strict mode
function displayOutput() {
    var value = this;
    // ...
}
```

...but I don't recommend it relative to other options. And if your code *isn't* in strict mode, that may not work well because the value will get converted to the object equivalent (`"string"` becomes a string object instead of primitive, like `new String("string")`).

If you don't care what `this` is inside the target function but you want to bind arguments to it, pass `null` as the first argument to bind:

```
button[i].addEventListener("click", displayOutput.bind(null, button[i].value));
```

**But**, if you don't use `this` in `displayOutput`, you don't need `bind` at all. Instead, just pass `displayOutput`:

```
button[i].addEventListener("click", displayOutput);
```

That will call `displayOuput` with `this` set to the element (`button[i]`), and you can just use `this.value`:

```
function displayOutput() {
    var value = this.value;
    // ...
}
```

Also, no matter whether you use `bind` or not, `displayOutput` will be passed an `Event` object (after any bound arguments; it's the first argument if there are no bound arguments), so you could also do:

```
function displayOutput(event) {
    var value = event.currentTarget.value;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What a clear and helpful answer. Huge bonus points for showing me how to make it work without bind. Which is what I was originally trying to do. Although, it did not work quite as you wrote it. I had to add .value

function displayOutput() {
    var value = this.value;